# Sending empty string value for a custom request header using cURL

Tags: c, linux, apache, http, curl

I am trying to send a HTTP POST custom request header (X-Privet-Token) with value set to "" using cURL on a Linux machine. Following is my command:

```
curl -k -sI POST -H "X-Privet-Token:" -H "Content-Type: application/json" --trace-ascii --data "action=start&user=xyz@gmail.com" https://127.0.0.1/privet/register
```

I would like to send an empty string to the server.

Am I missing something?

Comment: try putting a linebreak at the end of the header? "X-Privet-Token:\n"

Comment: I tried that, however, it did not work.

Comment: Ever tried what happens when send "`X-Privet-Token: `" or just skip that header ? And what is the _exact_ effect that is happening on the server side ?

Comment: I get the following response on the server side : HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://www.google.com/

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request .

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following syntax to set a custom header with an empty value

```
curl -H "X-custom-header;" <some host>
```

From the man page:

```sh
man curl
...
       -H, --header <header>
...
If you send the custom header with no-value then its header must be termi-
              nated with a semicolon, such as -H "X-Custom-Header;" to send "X-Custom-Header:".
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it is an old question, but I think it is worth to answer it.

I faced a similar issue when calling the *privet/info* API call in a Java client app, I realized the header was not sent when it was empty. If you want to set an empty header, try to use **\"\"** (that's what privet documentation states for /privet/info API call):

```
curl -k -sI POST -H "x-privet-token: \"\"" -H "Content-Type: application/json" --trace-ascii --data "action=start&user=xyz@gmail.com" https://127.0.0.1/privet/register
```

On the other hand, the *privet/register* API call requires a valid x-privet-token. Leaving the *x-privet-token* header empty, 'curl' may be ommiting it.

Having said that, the error you are getting occurs when the endpoint is not advertising */privet/register* API, probably because it's already registered. You can check the APIs that the device is exposing examining the */privet/info* response.

Comment: This does not set an empty header, it sets a header with a value of `""` (i.e., 2 double quotes)